# ToC with pauses and images in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, table-of-contents, presentations

I've been using the [pausesection] option on my table of contents and that is working well. 
However I'd like to be able to print, on the same page different images syncronized with the table of contents pauses on the other side of the slide.

I don't want to have the images start once the toc has finished, but right when the subsection shows

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[30pt]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Luebeck}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\AtBeginSection[]{\subsection{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Index}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.50\textwidth}
\tableofcontents[pausesections]
\column{0.50\textwidth}
space for sync images
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{test1}
\subsection{test11}
\frame{}

\section{test2}
\subsection{test21}
\frame

\end{document}
```

[image: On the right column I want to print images with respect to the different sections]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea how this could be done automatically, would require a bit of patching of `beamer`'s internals. The following does it manually, using `minipage`s, which is not adviced by `beamer`, but for some reasons we have to use `\only` *before* `\tableofcontents`, or else the `\only` macros for the images wouldn't work correctly.

```latex
\documentclass[30pt]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Luebeck}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\AtBeginSection[]{\subsection{}}

\usepackage{duckuments} % only to get random duck images for example-image-duck

\makeatletter
\newcounter{tocimage}
\newcommand*\tocimage[2][]
  {%
    \only<+>
      {%
        \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
        \else
          \begingroup
            \includegraphics[{#1}]{#2}%
          \endgroup
        \fi
      }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Index}
  \leavevmode
  \rlap
    {%
      \hskip.5\textwidth
      \begin{minipage}[c]{.5\textwidth}
        \tocimage[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%
        \tocimage{}% no image for section 2
        \tocimage[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%
      \end{minipage}%
    }%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{.5\textwidth}
    \tableofcontents[pausesections]
  \end{minipage}%
\end{frame}

\section{test1}
\subsection{test11}
\frame{}

\section{test2}
\subsection{test21}
\frame

\section{test3}
\subsection{test31}
\frame

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was afraid it was quite difficult to achieve, anyhow I have only a few subsections ad sections, I believe I'll go and do it manually :( 

Thank you for your kind reply!

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the fact beamer doen't like minipages? I've been using them quite a lot

Comment: @suxdavide well that was formulated a bit of unlucky. `beamer` doesn't dislike `minipage`s *per se*, but it does advocate for using its own `columns` mechanism like you did in your MWE to separate contents into columns, which I didn't use and instead built manually with `minipage`s.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!